# Dynamic Crm 2013 : Get Attributes (only the attr in Form) in MetaData of Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I want to Retrive Metadata Attributes of Entity , but XrmServiceToolkit gave me all attributes , i want to fillter only the Active Attributes that on the Form and not all attributes.

which parameter tell me if the Attribute in Form or Not in Form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Metadata of an entity contains always all the attributes. Dynamics CRM 2011/2013 support multiple forms, so you need to query the specific form (`SystemForm` entity) and parse the formxml result to know which attributes are inside the form.

If you are executing the JavaScript inside the form you want to query, you can also access the `Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes` collection without querying the metadata.

```js
var attributes = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get();
for (var i in attributes) {
    //
}
```

Comment: I want to retrive list of all Entity Relations of some entity , and get the attributes that active in Default Form in each Entity

Comment: so you need to query the `SystemForm` entity